# How to execute DB2 stored procedure multiple times to update multiple records

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I want to create a mapping to update multiple records, more than 1000 records in DB2 using/calling a stored procedure. We will send the parameters to call the stored procedure. How to implement that?

1. Target is DB2 table
2. We should use DB2 stored procedure to update or insert records

How to create the mapping-target to execute stored procedure multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Informatica to run anything in loop. However you can put DC code into a stored procedure, setup and schedule a workflow to run at desired frequency.